# Slight query issue, when trying to do a join table with rails 2.3.5

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, join

I have this query put together which performs fine.

```
     search = Artist.where(:status => "active").where("upcoming_events_count > 0").order("echonest_external_popularity DESC").limit(limit))
```

The issue is that I'd like to add one more check, which is on another table ArtistPhoto.  The match needs to make sure that the Artist (from the artist_id) also contains a valid photo.

I have the query working find independently:

```
     ArtistPhoto.where("artist_id = ? and artist_photos.primary = ?", self.id, true).first
```

If anyone can assist with getting the join into 1 query that would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `joins` to add the other association:

```
search = Artist.joins(:artist_photos).
                where("artist_photos.primary = ?", true).
                where(...) # other filters here
```

This answer assumes you have a `has_many :artist_photos` on your `Artist` model.